# What to use PATCH or POST?

Tags: rest, http, state-machine

I had a quiet long debate with my colleague about the proper HTTP verb to be used for one of our operation that changes the STATE of a resource.

Suppose we have a resource called `WakeUpLan` that tries to send event to a system connected in a network. This is kind of a Generic State Machine,

```
{
id: 1,
retries: {
 idle: 5, // after 5 retries it went to FAILED state
 wakeup: 0,
 process: 0,
 shutdown: 0
},
status: 'FAILED',
// other attributes
}`
```

`IDLE --> WAKEUP ---> PROCESS ---> SHUTDOWN` `|` `---->` `[FAILED]`

Every state has a retry mechanism, i.e in `IDLE` case it tries for `x` times to `transition` to `WAKEUP` and after `x` retries it dies out and goes to `FAILED` state.

All the `FAILED` resource can be again manually restarted or retried one more time from some interface.

So, we have a confusion regarding which HTTP verb best suits in this case.

In my opinion, it is just a change in `status` and resetting retry count to 0, so that our retry mechanism can catch this and try in next iteration.
so it should be a pure `PATCH` request

`PATCH retry/{id}`
`{state: 'IDLE'}`

But my colleague opposes it to be a POST request as this is a pure action and should be treated as POST.
I am not convinced because we are not creating any new resource but just updating existing resource that our REST server already knows about it.

I would like to know and corrected if I am wrong here.

Any suggestions/advices are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestions/advices are welcome.

The reference implementation of the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the world wide web.  The world wide web is built on a foundation of URI, HTTP, and HTML -- and HTML form processing is limited to `GET` and `POST`.

So `POST` must be *an* acceptable answer.  After all, the web was catastrophically successful.

`PATCH`, like `PUT`, allows you to communicate changes to a representation of a resource.  The semantics are more specific than POST, which allows the client to better take advantage.  So if all you are doing is creating a message that describes local edits to the representation of the resource, then PATCH is a fine choice.

Don't overlook the possibilities of PUT -- if the size of the complete representation of the resource is of roughly the same order as the representation of your PATCH document, then using PUT may be a better choice, because of the [idempotent semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2).

> I am not convinced because we are not creating any new resource but just updating existing resource that our REST server already knows about it.

[POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) is much more general than "create a new resource".  Historically, there has been a lot of confusion around this point (the language in the early HTTP specifications didn't help).

Answer (score 1):

### HTTP Basics

#### PATCH

What is `PATCH` actually? `PATCH` is a HTTP method defined in [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) that is similar to patching code in software engineering, where a change to one or multiple sources should be applied in order to transform the target resource to a desired outcome. Thereby a client is calculating a set of instructions the target system has to apply fully in order to generate the requested outcome. These instruction are usually called "patch", in the words of RFC 5789 such a set of instructions is called "patch document".

RFC 5789 does not define in which representation such a patch document need to be transferred from one system to the other. For JSON-based representations [application/json-patch+json (RFC 6902)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) can be used which contains certain instructions like `add`, `replace`, `move`, `copy`, ... that are more or less clear on what they are doing but the RFC also describes each of the available instructions further.

A further JSON-based, but totally different take on how to inform a system on how to change a resource (or document) is captured in [application/merge-patch+json (RFC 7386)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386). In contrast to json-patch, this media-type does define a set of default rules to apply on receiving a JSON based representation to the actual target resource. Here, a single JSON representation of the modified state is sent to the server that only contains fields and objects that should be changed by the server. Default rules define that fields to be removed from the target resource need to be nullified in the request while fields that should change need to contain the new value to apply. Fields that remain unchanged can be left out in the request.

If you read through RFC 5789, you will find merge-patch as more of a hack though. Compared to json-patch, a merge-patch representation lacks the control of the actual sequence the instructions are applied, which might not always be necessary, as well as the lack of changing multiple, different resources at once.

`PATCH` itself is not idempotent. For a `json-patch` patch document it is pretty clear that applying the same instructions multiple times may lead to different results, i.e. if you remove the first field. A `merge-patch` document here behaves similar to a "partial `PUT`" request that so many developers perform due to pragmatism, even though the actual operation still does not guarantee idempotency. In order to avoid applying the same patch to the same resource unintentionally multiple times, i.e. due to network errors while transmitting the patch document, it is recommended to use `PATCH` alongside [conditional requests (RFC 7232)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232). This guarantees that the changes are only applied to a specific version of the resource and if that resource had changed either through a previous request or by an external source, the request would be declined to prevent data loss. This is basically optimistic locking.

A requirement that all patch documents have to fulfill is, that they need to be applied atomically. Either all the changes are applied or none at all. This puts some transaction burden onto the service provider.

#### POST

`POST` method is defined in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) as:

> requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics.

This is basically a get-free-out-of-jail-card that lets you do anything you want or have to do here. You are free to define the syntax and structure to receive on a certain endpoint. Most of these so-called "REST APIs" consider POST as the C in CRUD, which it can be used for, but is just an oversimplification of what it actually can do for you. HTML basically only supports `POST` and `GET` operations so `POST` requests are used for sending all kinds of data to the server to start of backing processes, create new resources such as blog-posts, Q&A, videos, ... but also to delete or update stuff.

The rule of thumb here is, if a new resource is created as an outcome of triggering a POST request on a certain URI the response code should be `201 Created` containing a HTTP response header `Location`  with a URI as a value that points to the newly created resource. In any other case `POST` does not map to the C (create) of the CRUD stereotype.

### REST-related

REST isn't a protocol but an architectural style. As Robert (Uncle Bob) C. Martin [stated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&t=860s), *architecture is about intent* and REST intention is about decoupling clients from servers which allows the latter one to evolve freely by minimizing interoperability issues due to changes introduced by the server.

These are very strong benefits if your system should still work in decades to come. However, these benefits are unfortunately not obtained easily. As outlined in Fieldings [dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) to benefit from REST the mentioned constraints need to be followed strictly or otherwise couplings will remain increasing the likelihood of breaking clients due to changes. Fielding later on ranted about people that did either not read or understand his dissertation and clarified what a REST API has to do [in a nutshell](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).

This rant can be summarized into the following points:

- The API should adhere to and not violate the underlying protocol. Altough REST is used via HTTP most of the time, it is not restricted to this protocol.
- Strong focus on resources and their presentation via media-types.
- Clients should not have initial knowledge or assumptions on the available resources or their returned state (["typed" resource](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html)) in an API but learn them on the fly via issued requests and responses that teaches clients on what they can do next. This gives the server the freedom over its namespace and move around things it needs to without negatively impacting clients.

Based on this, REST is about using well-defined standards and adhering to the semantics of the protocols used as transportation facilities. Through the utilization of HATEOAS and stateless communication, the concepts that proved the Web to be scalable and evolution-friendly, the same interaction model that is used by humans in the Web is now used by applications in a REST architecture.

Common media-types provide the [affordance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817) on what a system might be able to do with data received for that payload while content-type negotiation guarantees that both, sender and receiver, are able to process and understand the payload correctly. The affordance may differ from media-type to media-type. A payload received for a `image/png` might be rendered and shown to the user while a `application/vnd.acme-form+json` might define a form where a server teaches a client on the elements of a request the server does support and a client can enter data and issue the request without having to actively know the method to use or target URI to send the data to as this is already given by the server. This not only removes the need for out-of-band (external) API documentation but also the need for a client to parse or interpret URIs as they are all provided by the server, accompanied by [link-relations](http://restcookbook.com/Resources/link-types/), that should be either [standardized by IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), follow common conventions such as [existing rel values microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values) or [ontologies like Dublin Core](http://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dc-html/), or represent [extension types as defined in RFC 5988 (Web linking)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-4.2).

### Question-related

With the introductory done, I hope that for a question like

> But my colleague opposes it to be a POST request as this is a pure action and should be treated as POST. I am not convinced because we are not creating any new resource but just updating existing resource that our REST server already knows about it

it is clear that there is no definite *yes* or *no* answer to this quest but more of a *it depends*.

There are a couple of questions that could be asked, i.e. like

- How many (different) clients will use the service? Are they all under your control? If so, you don't need REST, but you can still aim for it
- How is the client taught or instructed on to perform the update? Will you provide an external API documentation? Will you support a media-type that supports forms, such as [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html), [hal-forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [halo+json](http://halform.herokuapp.com), [Ion](https://ionspec.org/) or [Hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/)

In general, if you have multiple clients, especially ones that are not under your control, you might not know which capabilities they support. Here content-type negotiation is an important part. If a client supports `application/json-patch+json` it might also be able to calculate a patch document containing the instructions to apply onto the target resource. The chances that it will also support `PATCH` are also very likely as RFC 6902 mentions it. In such a case it would make sense to provide a `PATCH` endpoint the client can send the request to.

If the client supports `application/patch-merge+json` one might assume that it supports `PATCH` as well, as it is primarily intended for use with the HTTP PATCH method, according to RFC 7386. Here the update from a client side perspective is rather trivial as the updated document is send as is to the server.

In any other case though, it is less clear in what representation formats the changes will be transmitted to the server. Here, `POST` is probably the way to go. From a REST stance, an update here has probably to be similar to an update done to data that is edited in a Web form in your browser with the current content being loaded into each form-element and the client modifies these form elements to its liking and then submits the changes back to the server in probably an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or the like) structure. In such a case though, `PUT` would probably be more appropriate as in such a case you'd transmit the whole updated state of the resource back to the service and therefore perform a full update rather than a partial update on the target resource. The actual media-type the form will submit is probably defined in the media-type of the respective form. Note that this does not mean that you can't process `json-patch` or `merge-patch` documents in `POST` also.

The rule of thumb here would be, the more media-type formats and HTTP methods you support, the more likely different clients will be able to actually perform their task.

Answer (score -3):

I would say you're in the right since you are not creating any new resource.
Highlight the part that says use put when you modify the entire existing resource while use patch when you are modifying one component of existing resource.
More here
https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/

Comment: That article has nothing to do with REST. It's not even good web API design. It's also referencing a spec that's been out of date since 2014.